# Node.js unable to send partial text response to a request

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on chat application where it takes a long time to make a response.
So I am hoping the server can send partial text responses.

I tried this at the express server:

```
server.post('/ask', async function(req, res, next) {  
  res.write("hello")  
  setTimeout(function(){
    res.write("world")
    res.end();
  }, 5000)
});
```

And this at the web client:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "text";
xhr.open("POST", `${this.serverPath()}/ask`, true);
xhr.onprogress = function () {
    console.log("PROGRESS:", xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.send();
```

I am expecting onprogress to be fired twice.
First with hello, second time with helloworld.
But this didn't work. onprogress function is always fired with the complete response "helloworld". Not the partial ones.

What did I miss?

Comment: Nothing.  That's how a TCP socket works.  TCP sockets are stream-based, not packet-based.  Multiple sends can be buffered up into a single transmission, or even broken up in other ways, if need be.

Comment: @TimRoberts any easy way to achieve partial response in this case? otherwise the user has to wait for 10+ seconds without a response. I am also trying not to go into websocket which feels abit overkill

Comment: That's just not how HTTP works.  The only way is to drive it from the CLIENT side -- have the client ask for feedback every second or two, each as a separate transaction.

Comment: Web sockets aren't an overkill btw. Your use case is exactly what they are meant to do

Comment: @TimRoberts - TCP ultimately sends data in packets so you're incorrect when you say it's not packet-based.  It's just that the sending TCP stack gets to decide how to break the content into packets and when exactly to stop waiting for more data and send.  Also, the `res` object in Express itself is a stream object and it gets to decide when to actually do a tcp write (buffering in some cases).